# Can a LED lights output more light than they are designed to, due to mishandling?

Tags: led

It happens with incandescent lightbulbs sometimes, that they shine brighter due to a mishap by mishandling, and then end up dying earlier.

Is the same possible with LEDs? Mishandling can cause parts to become loose or otherwise out of place which would cause the LED to shine brighter than intended.

Comment: do you mean physical mishandling, like dropping them on the floor?

Comment: @Jasen yes, that is correct

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You can overdrive the led (more voltage/current than recommended) and it will produce more light, at the expense of the life of the led. LEDs are temperamental so even a little bit more current will cause the life to shrink exponentially.

Comment: Overdrive due to mishandling or mishap, does that happen? Or are you for only referring to intentionaly overdriving the LED.

Comment: @larry909 If you mistreat an LED to the point where permanent damage occurs, it will shine less bright from that point on. I do not think you can damage it in a way that it produces more light.

Comment: @hekete It sounds like the OP may be talking about an LED **bulb** rather than the bare LED itself. If that's the case I would think almost anything could happen if the bulb is mistreated, including faults that would make the bulb brighter...for a while.

Comment: if OP's asking about LED bulbs it's off topic.